# Can I use PC PSU as power adapter for monitor?

Tags: power-supply

I have a monitor with 5.5mm 2.5mm connector that consumes 12V 5A, but I don't have 12V 5A power adapter.

Before I buy a power adapter I want to check if this monitor even works.

My plan is to short green and black wires on main PC PSU connector, make a Molex to 5.5mm 2.5mm connector, and use PC PSU as the power adapter for monitor.

So before I do this, I want to know if it even works and doesn't kill the monitor.

Answer (score 2):

After some tests i found out that this works ok (with my pc-psu at least).

So yes i can power 12v device with molex on my pc-psu.

Answer (score 0):

ATX power supplies are not intended to be used as general purpose power supplies.

If you are only going to use the 12V output it may not work. However it might work.

We cannot know how your power supply behaves if you try to use it as a general purpose power supply.